# How do I present a view controller over current context with a custom transition?

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, uikit

I am running into a problem with view controller containment and wanting to present view controllers "over current context" with a custom presentation/animation.

I have a root view controller that has two child view controllers that can be added and removed as children to the root. When these child view controllers present a view controller I want the presentation to be over current context so that when the child that is presenting is removed from the view heirarchy and deallocated the presented modal will be removed as well. Also, if child A presents a view controller, I would expect child B's 'presentedViewController' property to be nil in an "over current context" presentation even if A was still presenting.

Everything works as expected when I set the `modalPresentationStyle` of my presented view controller to `overCurrentContext`, and if the child view controllers have `definesPresentationContext` set to true.

This doesn't work when I would expect it to however if I have `modalPresentationStyle` set to `custom` and override `shouldPresentInFullscreen` returning false in my custom presentation controller.

Here is an example illustrating the problem:

```
import UIKit

final class ProgressController: UIViewController {
    private lazy var activityIndicatorView = UIActivityIndicatorView(activityIndicatorStyle: .white)
    private lazy var progressTransitioningDelegate = ProgressTransitioningDelegate()

    // MARK: Lifecycle

    override init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String?, bundle nibBundleOrNil: Bundle?) {
        super.init(nibName: nibNameOrNil, bundle: nibBundleOrNil)

        setup()
    }

    required public init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)

        setup()
    }

    override public func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0, alpha: 0)

        view.addSubview(activityIndicatorView)
        activityIndicatorView.startAnimating()
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    }

    override public func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

        activityIndicatorView.center = CGPoint(x: view.bounds.width/2, y: view.bounds.height/2)
    }

    // MARK: Private

    private func setup() {
        modalPresentationStyle = .custom
        modalTransitionStyle = .crossDissolve
        transitioningDelegate = progressTransitioningDelegate
    }
}

final class ProgressTransitioningDelegate: NSObject, UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate {
    func presentationController(forPresented presented: UIViewController, presenting: UIViewController?, source: UIViewController) -> UIPresentationController? {
        return DimBackgroundPresentationController(presentedViewController: presented, presenting: source)
    }
}

final class DimBackgroundPresentationController: UIPresentationController {
    lazy var overlayView: UIView = {
        let v = UIView()
        v.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0, alpha: 0.5)
        return v
    }()

    override var shouldPresentInFullscreen: Bool {
        return false
    }

    override func presentationTransitionWillBegin() {
        super.presentationTransitionWillBegin()

        overlayView.alpha = 0
        containerView!.addSubview(overlayView)
        containerView!.addSubview(presentedView!)

        if let coordinator = presentedViewController.transitionCoordinator {
            coordinator.animate(alongsideTransition: { _ in
                self.overlayView.alpha = 1
            }, completion: nil)
        }
    }

    override func containerViewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.containerViewDidLayoutSubviews()

        overlayView.frame = presentingViewController.view.bounds
    }

    override func dismissalTransitionWillBegin() {
        super.dismissalTransitionWillBegin()

        let coordinator = presentedViewController.transitionCoordinator
        coordinator?.animate(alongsideTransition: { _ in
            self.overlayView.alpha = 0
        }, completion: nil)
    }
}

class ViewControllerA: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

        definesPresentationContext = true

        let vc = ProgressController()
        self.present(vc, animated: true) {
        }
    }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let container = UIScrollView()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        container.frame = view.bounds
        view.addSubview(container)

        let lhs = ViewControllerA()
        lhs.view.backgroundColor = .red

        let rhs = UIViewController()
        rhs.view.backgroundColor = .blue

        addChildViewController(lhs)
        lhs.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.bounds.width, height: view.bounds.height)
        container.addSubview(lhs.view)
        lhs.didMove(toParentViewController: self)

        addChildViewController(rhs)
        rhs.view.frame = CGRect(x: view.bounds.width, y: 0, width: view.bounds.width, height: view.bounds.height)
        container.addSubview(rhs.view)
        rhs.didMove(toParentViewController: self)


        container.contentSize = CGSize(width: view.bounds.width * 2, height: view.bounds.height)
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
//        let rect = CGRect(x: floor(view.bounds.width/2.0), y: 0, width: view.bounds.width, height: view.bounds.height)
//        container.scrollRectToVisible(rect, animated: true)
    }
}
```

1. This will show a ViewController with a scroll view that contains two child view controllers
2. The red view controller on the left hand side will present a progress view controller that should present over current context.
3. If the view controller was presented properly "over current context" then you would be able to scroll the scrollview, and if you checked the "presentedViewController" property of the blue right hand side view controller then it should be nil. Neither of these are true.

If you change the `setup()` function on `ProgressController` to:

```
private func setup() {
    modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
    modalTransitionStyle = .crossDissolve
    transitioningDelegate = progressTransitioningDelegate
}
```

the presentation/view heirarchy will behave as expected, but the custom presentation will not be used.

Apple's docs for `shouldPresentInFullscreen` seem to indicate that this should work:

> The default implementation of this method returns true, indicating
>   that the presentation covers the entire screen. You can override this
>   method and return false to force the presentation to display only in
>   the current context.
>
> If you override this method, do not call super.

I tested this in Xcode 8 on iOS 10 and Xcode 9 on iOS 11 and the above code would not work as expected in either case.

Comment: Maybe this isn't supported, but what would the purpose of the `shouldPresentInFullscreen` on presentation controller be if not to provide this functionality? Overriding it in this example does nothing when the docs seem to indicate that it should.

Comment: Maybe I am confused. I am explicitly returning false from `shouldPresentInFullscreen` to turn this into a non-fullscreen transition, but this doesn't behave like a current context transition (or over current context)   when I return false. Changing what is returned does nothing from what I can tell for a custom presentation.

Comment: Okay, I looked into this further. If you put a calculated override in front of the child's `definedPresentationContext`, it is never even being called when the presentation style is `.custom`. So I would have to say that this feature doesn't work as advertised. It's easy to change the _animation_ for a `.currentContext` but I don't think you can usefully change the presentation controller.

Comment: Possibly related to the discussion here: http://petersteinberger.com/blog/2015/uipresentationcontroller-popover-detection/ Notice how he points out that the custom presentation controller doesn't do the walk up the view controller hierarchy properly from the source. In fact, it doesn't even know the source; the only info it has the presenting view controller, and that's the _root_ view controller!

Comment: And read this too, please: https://github.com/IcaliaLabs/Presentr/issues/17 Read the whole history of the comments; you'll see that they conclude that `shouldPresentInFullscreen` does nothing.

Comment: I'm using Xcode 9 beta 2 and returning true works well. Try it again.

Answer (score 4):

I'm going to guess that you've found a bug. The docs say that `shouldPresentInFullscreen` can turn this into a `currentContext` presentation, but it does nothing. (In addition to your test and my test, I found a few online complaints about this, leading me to think that that's the case.)

The conclusion is that you cannot get the default `currentContext` behavior (where the runtime consults the source view controller and up the hierarchy looking for `definesPresentationContext`) if you use presentation style of `.custom`.

I suggest filing a bug with Apple.

Comment: By the way, I filed a bug report.

Comment: I will file one as well. I had a coworker look at this as well, and thought I was going crazy.

Comment: You might be going crazy, but I don't think this is the proof. :)

Comment: I also reported the issue via feedbackassistant.apple.com

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this same problem myself recently.  You're right that UIKit documentation seems to be misleading about the behavior of UIPresentationController.shouldPresentInFullscreen.  However, when experimenting with this property, I discovered that when it's set to NO, the UITransitionView is added to the window, but when it's set to YES, it's added to UITransitionView of the nearest presented UIViewController.  This does not include child UIViewControllers whose definesPresentationContext property returns YES.

However, if you present a UIViewController with UIModalPresentationStyleOverCurrentContext on a UIViewController with definesPresentationContext == YES, then UIKit inserts a presentation container view in the hierarchy above the presenting view controller.  If you present upon *that* presented UIViewController using UIModalPresentationStyleCustom with a UIPresentationController whose shouldPresentInFullscreen property returns NO, the presented UIViewController's presentation container view will be inserted into the first UIViewController that was presented over the current context of the child UIViewController.

Answer (score 1):

I also think that `shouldPresentInFullscreen` does essentially nothing. A bug if you ask me.

To fix this, you should override `frameOfPresentedViewInContainerView` and return the adjusted frame.

Then, override `containerViewWillLayoutSubviews` and set `self.presentedViewController.view.frame = self.frameOfPresentedViewInContainerView`. Here you should also set the frames of any background or chrome views you might have.